# Why is my GPU running out of memory with Tensorflow and a relatively small dataset and neural net

Tags: tensorflow

I was going through the `Kaggle Bird Audio Classification with Tensorflow` example (https://www.kaggle.com/code/lkergalipatak/bird-audio-classification-with-tensorflow) when I came across behavior from Tensorflow that surprised me - namely how much GPU memory was claimed using a fairly small dataset and a not terribly large net.

I have a `RTX 3080 Ti` with `12 GB RAM`, which I had thought was a reasonable size for anything other than transformers, LLMs and such. However, (an abridged version) of the first few cells of the Kaggle example are as follows:

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def load_wav_16k_mono(filename):
    # Load encoded wav file
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    # Decode wav (tensors by channels) 
    wav, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(file_contents, desired_channels=1)
    # Removes trailing axis
    wav = tf.squeeze(wav, axis=-1)
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    # Goes from 44100Hz to 16000hz - amplitude of the audio signal
    wav = tfio.audio.resample(wav, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=16000)
    return wav
    
POS = os.path.join('data', 'Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips')
NEG = os.path.join('data', 'Parsed_Not_Capuchinbird_Clips')
```

Up until this point, `nvidia-smi` only showed about `750Mib/12288MiB` of my GPU memory being used, but after I started to define my dataset with these commands:

```
pos = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS+'/*.wav')
neg = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(NEG+'/*.wav')
```

My usage jumped to `10557MiB/122288MiB`. I assumed this was just Tensorflow reserving space on a GPU for a job it knew was coming. The total size of this dataset (according the memory used by the POS and NEG folders as given by `Disk Usage Analyzer`) was about `425 MiB` - Well below `10557MiB`.

I then finished making the dataset and set-up the preprocessing pipeline:

```
positives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((pos, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones(len(pos)))))
negatives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((neg, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(len(neg)))))
data = positives.concatenate(negatives)

def preprocess(file_path, label): 
    wav = load_wav_16k_mono(file_path)
    wav = wav[:48000]
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([48000] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
    wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav],0)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=320, frame_step=32)
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
    return spectrogram, label
    
data = data.map(preprocess)
data = data.cache()
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
data = data.batch(16)
data = data.prefetch(8)

train = data.take(36)
test = data.skip(36).take(15)
```

The net was constructed as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1491, 257,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('Adam', loss='BinaryCrossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

model.summary()
```

which gives:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 1489, 255, 16)     160       
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 1487, 253, 16)     2320      
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 6019376)           0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               770480256 
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 770482865 (2.87 GB)
Trainable params: 770482865 (2.87 GB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

So, I would think I'm using less than `3.5GB` out of `10.6GB` to store the dataset and the net on my GPU. However, when I try to fit the net using:

```
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=4, validation_data=test)
```

I almost immediately get:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:
...
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,1,3,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d/Relu}}]]
```

Why am I running out of memory here? The only thing I can think of is that individual audio file are larger than the images I usually deal with, but the total memory required by all the data doesn't seem to be that much nor is the net terribly deep. So, what am I missing here? Why do I seemingly need so much memory and what should I do about it? How can I determine the amount of memory I actually need? I'm thinking I also need to account for the memory needed for the actual calculation.

Comment: Well your model has 770M parameters, that is huge, several times larger than networks for ImageNet, so 2.7GB of memory is used only to store the weights in the GPU, so use a smaller model, add conv layers.

Comment: Or you can use GlobalPooling layers instead of Flatten.